# Powershell to change Advance System Properties

Tags: powershell, system-setting

Is there a way in powershell to change advance system settings in the remote tab? Picture is attached for reference.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[uint32]$atsc = 1
[uint32]$mfe = 1
$ts = Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\CIMv2\TerminalServices -ClassName Win32_TerminalServiceSetting
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $ts -MethodName SetAllowTSConnections -Arguments @{AllowTSConnections = $atsc; ModifyFirewallException = $mfe}
```

Comment: Get an error when doing this:

Invoke-CimMethod : Invalid operation 
At line:4 char:1
+ Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $ts -MethodName SetAllowTSConnections -Arguments @ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Win32_TerminalS...= "CMPNAME"):CimInstance) [Invoke-CimMethod], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041016,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand

Comment: What version of Windows are you running on?   Can you show the exact code you're using